# how to "docker run" a shell session on a minimal linux install and immediately tear down the container?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, docker

I just started using Docker, and I like it very much, but I have a clunky 
workflow that I'd like to streamline.   When I'm iterating on my Dockerfile script
I will often test things out after a build by launching a 
bash session,  running some commands, finding out that such 
and such package didn't get installed correctly, then
going back and tweaking my Dockerfile.

Let's say I have built my image and tagged it as buildfoo, I'd run it like
this:

```
      $>  docker run -t -i  buildfoo 

              ... enter some bash commands.. then  ^D to exit
```

Then I will have a container running that I have to clean up. Usually I just nuke everything like this:

```
docker rm --force `docker ps -qa`
```

This works OK for me.. However, I'd rather not have to manually remove the 
container.

Any tips gratefully accepted !

---

**Some Additional Minor Details:**

Running minimal centos 7 image and using  bash as my shell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please use `-rm` flag of docker run command. `--rm=true` or just `--rm`.

It automatically remove the container when it exits (incompatible with `-d`). Example:

```
docker run -i -t --rm=true centos /bin/bash
```

or

```
docker run -i -t --rm centos /bin/bash
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `--rm=false`?

Comment: updated the answer correctly. thanks for pointing out @Renaud Pacalet

Answer (score 4):

Even though the above still works, the command below makes use of Docker's newer syntax

```
docker container run -it --rm centos bash
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [the alias `dr`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/b010ab51974ac7de6162cdcbff795d7b9e84fd67/.bash_aliases#L25)

```
alias dr='docker run -it --rm'
```

That gives you:

```
dr myimage
ls
...
exit
```

No more container running.